# twig template returns html characters

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a problem relation with twig template.

it returns the raw html characters instead of html markup.

```
<?php
/* HomepageController.php */

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HomepageController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/homepage/")
     */
    public function homepage()
    {
        return $this->render('homepage/homepage.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'this will be title',
        ]);
    }
}
```

homepage.html.twig

```
<h1>this should show html content</h1>
  <p>{{ title }} </p>
```

browser output

```
<h1>this should show html content</h1>
  <p>this will be title </p>
```

twig.yaml

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    exception_controller: null
```

*do you know what is the configuration i am missing to set*

Comment: Have you tried to use `raw` filter? Like `{{ variable|raw }}`?

Comment: [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-05-04/how-to-remove-html-markups-on-twig) might help

Comment: What's the content of the page if you use "view source" in your Browser?

Comment: You aren't setting the content type to text anywhere right?

Comment: both of the things did not work for me, i found the solution as below.

Answer (score 0):

this was because the priority was set in the file. as just json.
added html and it worked.

*fos.rest.yaml*

```
format_listener:
rules:
  - {
      path: "^/",
      priorities: ["json","html"],
      fallback_format: json,
      prefer_extension: false,
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally twig converts all applicable characters to html entities (see also [html_entites](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in PHP doc).

If you want twig to not do this conversion you need to add `|raw` behind the variable (e.g. `{{ code|raw }}`.

The reason behind this default behaviour is to prevent users to inject malicious code into your website (e.g. including javascript code).

Tip: Try to avoid html code in variables where possible. Where it is not possible ensure that the value can not contain html from user inputs.

Comment: There is no `html` inside the variable. The whole template is outputted as plain text